# Prove that it is always possible to subdivide a given trapezium into two similar trapeziums.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Given that ABCD is a trapezium with AB // DC. Let $a = AB \lt CD = b$, $DA = c$ and $BC$ be also known.

[image]

Prove that there is a line PQ (with P on DA and Q on BC) drawn parallel to AB such that (Trap ABQP) ~ (Trap PQCD).

If the title is true, then

(1) How far is P from A (in terms of a, b, c)? and

(2) How can PQ be constructed in the Euclidean way?

Obviously, the trapeziums are equi-angular.

Comment: What does $\sim$ stands for?

Comment: If you extend DA and CB until they intersect, say at X, then you're asking for XP to be the geometric mean between XA and XD, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Draw BD and AC.

Comment: Euclid VI, 13 constucts a geometric mean, or a "mean proportional".

Comment: @user170039 "M ~ N" stands for "the object M **is similar to** object N".

Comment: @imranfat How does drawing those lines help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is enough to construct $PQ$ in such a way that $\frac{AB}{PQ}=\frac{PQ}{CD}$, i.e. to construct the geometric mean of $AB$ and $CD$. Here it is a possible approach, exploiting the power of a point with respect to a circle.

[image]

1. Let $E\in CD$ be a point such that $AE\parallel BC$;
2. Let $\Gamma$ the circumcircle of $ADE$ and $CF$ (with $F\in\Gamma$) a tangent to $\Gamma$;
3. Let $G\in CD$ be such that $CG=CF$;
4. Let $P\in AD$ be such that $PG\parallel BC$;
5. Let $Q\in BC$ be such that $PQ\parallel AB$.

[image]

As an alternative way based on the same principle,

1. Let $X=AD\cap BC$;
2. Let $\Gamma$ be a circle with diameter $AD$;
3. Let $T\in\Gamma$ be such that $XT$ is tangent to $\Gamma$;
4. Let $P\in AD$ be such that $XP=CT$;
5. Let $Q\in BC$ be such that $PQ\parallel AB$.

Comment: After posting this, I am working on it too. I am also using the power of a point to construct the geometric mean but my E is on DC produced. I think yours is more elegant.

Comment: @Mick if you voted this answer as correct, perhaps it is also best that you upvote it as well. Unless you already have in order to negate somebody's downvote, which would be unlikely here.

Answer (score 1):

I will call the length of PQ $y$ and that of AP $z$. Since the two trapeziums are similar, we must have $\frac ya=\frac by$, so $y=\sqrt{ab}$. The distance of P from A can then be calculated along the same lines:
$$\frac yz=\frac b{c-z}$$
$$y(c-z)=bz$$
$$z=\frac{yc}{b+y}=\frac{c\sqrt{ab}}{b+\sqrt{ab}}$$
To show the existence of the division asked for in the title, note that $\frac y{b+y}<1$ and therefore $z<c$; P therefore always lies on AD proper, not on the extension of it.

The line PQ can then be constructed easily, knowing that $AB\parallel PQ\parallel CD$.

Comment: Because the two figures are similar, they must be equi-angular. This further means PQ // AB // DC. Therefore finding the location of P is sufficient.

Comment: @Mick I've already found P, right? (AP=z, as I have stated in the answer.) Q is just a bonus.

Comment: Yes, you did find P.

Comment: I've edited my answer to only show the calculation of P, since that is the only point asked for.

Comment: Sorry for bothering you again. Your answer is still one step from complete. The title is asking  “is it always possible to subdivide ….”. Care to make a further update to guarantee that?

Comment: Yes, does this work?

Comment: Yes. That completes the task.